# Resharper C++ not showing templates

Tags: resharper

I have Resharper and Resharper C++ 10 with VS 2015. When coding C++ the templates are not showing.

[image]

In Resharper>Tools>Template explorer there are templates for C++.

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-16087) was fixed in the 2016.1.1 release. To report other bugs, please use R++'s [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project%3A+%7BReSharper+C%2B%2B%7D). Thank you!